# Cross variogram with a moving window

Tags: variance, matlab, image-processing

I need to generate cross variograms of images using moving windows. For that I use the following equation:

$$
\gamma_{jk}(h)=\frac{1}{2n(h)}\sum_{i=1}^{n(h)}\Big\{\big[dn_j(x_i)-dn_j(x_i+h)\big]\cdot\big[dn_k(x_i)-dn_k(x_i+h)\big]\Big\}
$$

The first part stands for one band(j) and next part of band k. To illustrate with sample matrices,

```
j =  1     2     3     4
     5     6     7     8
     9    10    11    12
    13    14    15    16

k = 17    18    19    20
    21    22    23    24
    25    26    27    28
    29    30    31    32
```

In actual case I am using 7 X 7 windows for large satellite images.

I also had to generate variograms from images for this work. For generation of variograms I had to consider only one band of data. For that case I used `nlfilter` for moving window and created a function to select and calculate values.

But for cross variograms, I am not able to decide upon what function to use. For this case the calculations will go like this:

> (1 - 2)(17 - 18) + (2 - 3)(18 - 19)

and so on.

Comment: As cross-posting is not encouraged, it would be better to remove your question on SO if you feel you'll be more likely to get a response there. As your question was asked few hours ago, it is fair to wait a little bit before cross-posting, though. Anyway, let's wait and see. If you get an acceptable response here, don't forget to remove the SO duplicate.

Comment: @chl definitely I will do that. I will remove one post once I get a favorable response in either of the sites.

Comment: As promised I have deleted this question from SO. Therefore deleted the first part in the question now - "I have also posted this question in StackOverflow...."

Answer (score 4):

I prefer a slight change of notation due to the many $n$'s appearing in the original. Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ designate the images.  Let $i$ and $j$ each designate *pairs* of indexes into the image rows and columns.  (Indexing goes from $1$ to $m$ for rows and $1$ to $n$ for columns.)  Let $h$ designate a *relative* index pair (so that its two entries are integers, either of which can be negative), also known as an *offset*.  Then, by definition, the value of the experimental cross-variogram of these images at an offset $h$ is

$$\gamma_{\alpha,\beta}(h)=\frac{1}{2n(h)}\sum_{i}\left(\alpha[i+h]-\alpha[i]\right)\left(\beta[i+h] - \beta[i]\right).$$

The sum ranges over all indexes $i$ for which both $i$ and $i+h$ are valid indexes into both images; $n(h)$ is the number of such indexes (easily computed in the same way by taking a similar sum of $1$'s).

By expanding the summand algebraically the calculation is reduced to the problem of obtaining

$$\sum_{i}\alpha[i+h]\beta[i]$$

for various $h$, both positive and negative, ranging from $(1-m,1-n)$ through $(m-1,n-1)$.

Let us say that the *reversal* of an image negates the indexes; that is, the value of the reversal of $\alpha$ at the pixel $h$ is the value of $\alpha$ at $(m+1,n+1)-h$.

Such a sum can be seen as the reversal of the convolution of the reversal of $\alpha$ with $\beta$.  It is best computed using [discrete Fourier transforms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Circular_convolution_theorem_and_cross-correlation_theorem) after first padding each image to the right and down with zeros.  The padding must extend to the range of the largest $h$ for which $\gamma$ needs to be computed.  Convolutions with Fourier transforms are obtained by taking the inverse Fourier transform (itself a scalar multiple of the FT) of the product of the FTs.

Direct computation of the variogram via its definition for a pair of $m$ by $n$ images requires up to $m n$ products and sums for each value of $h$.  Typically $O(m n)$ values of $h$ are needed.  The direct algorithm therefore has $O(m^2 n^2)$ computational cost, which is ridiculously large for moderate (megapixel) images.  The discrete Fourier transform costs at most $O(2m 2n \log(2m 2n))$ (assuming the maximum range of offsets $h$) and has to be applied only a constant number of times (3).  The reversals and paddings cost $O(2m 2n)$.  Thus the total cost is still only $O(12 m n \log(4 m n))$, a huge improvement.

---

As a simple example, take $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to be the matrices

```
1 2
3 4
```

and

```
5 6
7 8
```

After padding with zeros to the right and down (by two columns and two rows) *and reversing $\alpha$*, multiplying these two 4 by 4 matrices componentwise, and taking the inverse Fourier transform, we get

```
 8 0  14 23
 0 0   0  0
18 0  20 39
30 0  38 70
```

Rotating this right by 2 columns and 2 rows and reversing gives

```
0  0  0  0
0  8 23 14
0 30 70 38
0 18 39 20
```

If you think of the new row and column indexes ranging $-2, -1, 0, 1$, this new matrix is exactly $\sum_{i}\alpha[i+h]\beta[i]$ (indexed by $h$).  For example, the $h = (0,1)$ entry is 38 and indeed

$$\alpha[1,2]\beta[1,1] + \alpha[2,2]\beta[2,1] = 2 \times 5 + 4 \times 7 = 38.$$

Comment: can you please elaborate on how \sum_{i}\alpha[i+h]\beta[i] is obtained. I am not able to understand how to get it! Also it would greatly help me if you can point me to a resource which explains the above concepts in a simple manner.

Comment: @Chethan The last example shows explicitly how this sum is computed.  I learned about the FFT method from the geostatistics literature long ago, but it's a stretch to characterize this as "simple."  You can find an explicit description by Denis Marcotte in a [1996 paper](http://w3eos.whoi.edu/12.747/problem_sets/PS05/marcotte_96.pdf) in Computers & Geosciences.  A [2010 PowerPoint presentation by Jim Jennings](http://reproducibility.org/wikilocal/docs/data_flows.ppt) summarizes the approach (starting p. 14).